# How can we implement coreference resolution in a given text using python?

Tags: python, nlp

Currently I have identified the noun phrases in a given text.Now I need to identify whether there are references among them.

**For an example:**

There are two doors in a house,door_X and door_Y. 
If both doors are open the house is unsafe.

I need to map the "doors" in 2nd sentence with door_X and door_Y

Comment: Show your code.

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally co-reference resolution in NLP deals with anaphora resolution, i.e finding nouns that are referred by pronouns. In your problem  "doors" and "door_X" are both nouns, thereby what you are asking is not exactly the co-reference resolution problem studied in NLP.

However, I think you have to solve your problem by regular expression matching. You can also look to lemmatize the words to check references.

```
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
print(lemmatizer.lemmatize("doors"))
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion